# MS Access - Setting default value of a field to be the values of two other fields, seperated by an'_'

Tags: vba, ms-access, default-value, autofill

A form that I have at the moment has the field, `Skill_Name`.

There is a subform with two fields; `Employee_ID` (A combo box of all Employee_IDs) and `Emp_Skill_ID`.

Upon selecting an `Employee_ID`, I'd like the `Emp_Skill_ID` to autofill in the following format:

`Employee_ID`**_**`Skill_Name`

Example: `If Employee ID = 1234567, and Skill Name = AutoElec`, 
I want the `Emp_Skill_ID` to automatically be `1234567_AutoElec`.

If that's at all possible, it'd be much appreciated if someone could tell me how to do it.

Regards,
AUS_Doug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to handle the AfterUpdate in both Employee_ID and SkillName. Something like

```
Private Sub Employee_ID_AfterUpdate()
    UpdateEmp_Skill_ID
End Sub

Private Sub SkillName_AfterUpdate()
    UpdateEmp_Skill_ID
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateEmp_Skill_ID
   If Not IsNull(Employee_ID) And Not IsNull(SkillName) Then
        Emp_Skill_ID = Employee_ID & "_" & SkillName
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Cheers for that, worked nicely after an edit or two.